# Drag & drop items with itemtouchhelper, recyclerview and Firestore like Google Tasks

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, itemtouchhelper

I develop a todo app and would like to have a similar feature like Google Tasks has. Here my Google Tasks task list on my android app:

[Screenshot of Google Tasks android app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pu62G.png)

When I drag an drop one of those tasks vertically then my Google Tasks Gmail Webapp immediatly drops the task to the same position:

[Screenshot of Google Tasks Gmail Webapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpqEC.png)

This seems to be quite a challenge because I didn't find any code sample or documentation which does/explains exactly that with Firestore and the Firestore recycler adapter. There are some with code samples about Firebase Realtime Database but they don't help so much. I can't imagine that no one ever has coded this widely used functionality with Firestore.

Do you know any android app code published (on Github) or documentation which does/explains exactly this behaviour? Or any Firestore specialist who could help?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution, it allows the user to sort the documents in their Firestore collection.

I made a few reusable classes to implement this for any RecyclerAdapter / ViewHolder combination.

First, have your POJO implement `PositionAwareDocument`.

```
public interface PositionAwareDocument {
    public Double getPosition();

    public void setPosition(double position);
}
```

```
public class Experience implements Serializable, PositionAwareDocument {
    public String company;
    public String timeframe;
    public String jobTitle;
    public String jobDescription;
    public Double position;

    @ServerTimestamp
    public Date added;

    @Override
    public Double getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPosition(double position) {
        this.position = position;
    }
}
```

And then extend `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` (from FirebaseUI).

```
public abstract class IgnoreChangesFirestoreRecyclerAdapter<T, VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<T, VH> {
    private boolean mIgnoreChanges = false;

    public IgnoreChangesFirestoreRecyclerAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<T> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    public void setIgnoreChanges(boolean ignoreChanges) {
        mIgnoreChanges = ignoreChanges;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull ChangeEventType type, @NonNull DocumentSnapshot snapshot, int newIndex, int oldIndex) {
        if (!mIgnoreChanges) {
            super.onChildChanged(type, snapshot, newIndex, oldIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Creating the RecyclerAdapter remains the same, just extend `IgnoreChangesFirestoreRecyclerAdapter`:

```
public class ExperienceRecyclerAdapter extends IgnoreChangesFirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Experience, ExperienceViewHolder> {
    public ExperienceRecyclerAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Experience> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExperienceViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Experience model) {
        holder.setExperience(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getId(), model);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ExperienceViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ExperienceViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.experience_list_item, parent, false));
    }
}
```

Here's the secret sauce - the `ItemTouchHelper.Callback`:

```
import android.app.Activity;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;

public class FirestoreReorderableItemTouchHelperCallback<T extends PositionAwareDocument> extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {
    private final Activity mContext;
    private final IgnoreChangesFirestoreRecyclerAdapter<T, ?> mRecyclerAdapter;
    private final CollectionReference mCollectionReference;

    private int dragFrom = -1;
    private int dragTo = -1;

    public FirestoreReorderableItemTouchHelperCallback(
            Activity context,
            IgnoreChangesFirestoreRecyclerAdapter<T, ?> recyclerAdapter,
            CollectionReference collectionReference) {
        super(ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN, 0);
        mContext = context;
        mRecyclerAdapter = recyclerAdapter;
        mCollectionReference = collectionReference;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder source, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        if (dragFrom == -1) {
            dragFrom = source.getAdapterPosition();
        }
        dragTo = target.getAdapterPosition();
        mRecyclerAdapter.notifyItemMoved(source.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void clearView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder);
        if (dragFrom == -1) {
            return;
        }
        final PositionAwareDocument draggedItem = mRecyclerAdapter.getItem(dragFrom);
        final PositionAwareDocument draggedToItem = mRecyclerAdapter.getItem(dragTo);
        final String draggedId = mRecyclerAdapter.getSnapshots().getSnapshot(dragFrom).getId();
        final int itemCount = mRecyclerAdapter.getItemCount();

        mRecyclerAdapter.setIgnoreChanges(true);

        if (dragTo == itemCount - 1) {
            draggedItem.setPosition(draggedToItem.getPosition() + 100);
        } else if (dragTo == 0) {
            draggedItem.setPosition(draggedToItem.getPosition() / 2);
        } else {
            PositionAwareDocument draggedToNext = mRecyclerAdapter.getItem(dragTo > dragFrom ? dragTo + 1 : dragTo - 1);
            draggedItem.setPosition((draggedToItem.getPosition() + draggedToNext.getPosition()) / 2);
        }

        mCollectionReference.document(draggedId).update("position", draggedItem.getPosition()).addOnCompleteListener(mContext, task -> mRecyclerAdapter.setIgnoreChanges(false));
        dragFrom = dragTo = -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLongPressDragEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

And the rest is smooth sailing, here's where I make my RecyclerView and Adapter in my `onCreate`:

```
final CollectionReference experienceReference = mResumeFirestore.collection("experience");
final FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Experience> experienceOptions = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Experience>()
        .setQuery(experienceReference.orderBy("position"), Experience.class)
        .build();

mExperienceList.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
mExperienceList.setAdapter(mExperienceAdapter = new ExperienceRecyclerAdapter(experienceOptions) {

    @Override
    public void onDataChanged() {
        super.onDataChanged();
        setupEmptyView(mExperienceList, mExperienceEmpty, getItemCount());
    }
});
mExperienceTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(new FirestoreReorderableItemTouchHelperCallback<>(this, mExperienceAdapter, experienceReference));
mExperienceTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mExperienceList);
```

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: That's quite a cool solution Anthony. I've done the `(draggedToItem.position + draggedToNext.position) / 2` too and it worked great for my cases. Just be sure to do a test with many, many swaps, as you might hit the floating point granularity at some point (at least, so I've been told).

Comment: Hi @Anthony Chuinard, I have implemented your solution but nothing is happening, I have set my LayoutManager as it was skipping the layout without it, also what shoul be the initialization of setPosition value, should I pass it in the constructor? Help is appreciated

Comment: Edit: I got it working, thanks. Still I can't figure out how to initialize the positon for position aware document, should I pass it in the constructor, if yes, what default value should I pass. Thanks, any help will be appreciated

Edit 2: I figured it out thanks for your help